# when do you stop eating bread and etc.. for passover?

Tags: halacha, passover, zemanim, chametz-leaven

Do you stop eating bread once Seder starts or beginning of the morning of Seder day? Not sure about this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The precise time depends on exactly where you are. For example, the times for Glencoe Illinois for tomorrow are (courtesy of the chabad.org web site)

Finish Eating Chametz before: 10:38 AM

Sell and Burn Chametz before: 11:44 AM

go to the site and change the location to your zip code for relevant times.

http://www.chabad.org/calendar/view/day.asp?tdate=4/14/2014

Answer (score 1):

From Biblical law, you stop eating bread products at mid-day preceding the seder.  Rabbinical law extends the prohibition an extra hour before that to distance from the Biblical prohibition, and a further hour due to the possibility of confusion.

[Rambam laws of chometz ch. 1 Halacha 8-9](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/3501.htm#8)